# ECR lifecycle policies configured tracking

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecr

Is there a way to check if the **ECR repositories** do not have configured life-cycle policies?

[image: ecr-lifecycle-policy]

Currently, I have several repositories and would like to keep monitoring at each one of them if any are having life-cycle policies configured or not.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can track your ECR repositories with AWS Config: https://ap-southeast-1.console.aws.amazon.com/config/home?region=ap-southeast-1#/rules

There is a rule named - **ecr-private-lifecycle-policy-configured**.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/ecr-private-lifecycle-policy-configured.html

If there are any repositories without lifecycle config, the service will show you the list of **non-compliant** resources.

[image: ecr-private-lifecycle-policy-configured]

Comment: When I put this rule, it doesn't return anything.
I have admin access.

Comment: Have you clicked the Action (at the top) button and performed the Evaluation yet? or else it automatically runs daily every 24h

Comment: Sorry, I expressed myself wrong.
The rule that does not appear, when I look for the rule "ecr-private-lifecycle-policy-configured" in AWS Managed Rules it does not appear

Comment: It does not appear because you have not created it yet? or you created but does not see, check your current AWS Region.